# Zsh Line Editor History Filtering

Tags: zsh

One of the killer features of the readline line editor is the ability to type the first few characters of a command in one's history and then up-arrow to get to it. For instance, if I have 'grep "te' in the zle buffer, the up-arrow key iterates through grep commands whose first two search characters are 't' and 'e'. In my current zsh configuration, the up arrow key does not do such filtering. Are there zle commands/widgets that would give the type of filtering I want?

Answer (score 4):

The widget you are looking for is `history-beginning-search-backward`. You can bind it to up arrow using

```
bindkey "^[OA" history-beginning-search-backward
```

or

```
bindkey "^[[A" history-beginning-search-backward
```

depending on which escape sequence your up-arrow key sends (you can just use both, to be safe).

Comment: I was going to mention `down/up-line-or-search` but `history-beginning-search-backward` seem better (exactly because they use the whole input and not just the first token).